# Are there generic implementations of ARIES or other ACID-ensuring algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, acid

I have an application which I'd like to carry out certain actions atomically.
However, these actions are occurring on remote storage, and connections may drop, actions may fail, etc.

There's plenty of literature on how to enforce ACID properties - write-ahead logging, ARIES, etc. - but are there any generic implementations of these available?

Essentially what I'm looking for is some library/API/etc. where I can provide some stable storage (eg local hard disk) for logging, and perform my paricular actions (on an unstable remote storage), and have this hypothetical helper code handle the bulk of the ACID bookkeeping.

Obviously I would need to provide my own custom code rolling back certain things and soforth, but it seems like the high level of doing the logging, scanning the log, etc. could be generalized and wrapped in some library.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the [System.IO.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.log.aspx) namespace has log-related helpers, which might be close to what you're looking for, though it won't help directly with isolation on its own.  If you use LogRecordSequence, you get a pretty sophisticated log implementation underneath it.

Additionally [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) does all of this and is in the public domain.  I imagine its storage engine etc. would be somewhat separable, though you'd likely have to tear it apart yourself.